# Where can I restructure the html for the magento 2 product view page?

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, template

I am trying to theme my product view page but I cannot find the correct file to override in order to pull in all of the data where I want it.

in my `/app/design/frontend/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view` I can see a lot of different template files for some of the items being brought in, like Add to cart and details.

What I am looking for is a file where those are being pulled in from, so that If I wanted to I could wrap details.phtml and addtocart.phtml into two divs side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gxrobb

The file in which all these different product template files are structured is

```
magentoroot_dir/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

So to acheive your result you need to copy the **catalog_product_view.xml file** at the below location:

```
magentoroot_dir/app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

And use **move** XML directive to acheive your output.

> Hope this helps you, if yes then please upvote it and accept it as
>   answer.
>
> Thanks!